# How to Init properties of another control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

i have 2 web user controls in asp.net:
control1
control2

control1 include the properties:

```
    <script runat="server">
        public string MacName = "UNKOWN";
    </script>

    <h1><%= MacName %></h1>
```

control2 include the code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        control1 newControl = ((control1)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/control1.ascx"));
        newControl .[some code here]

        somePanel.Controls.Add(newControl);
    }
```

where is "[some code here]" i want to know how can i initialize the properties from control1 , MacName.

Comment: `control1 newControl =` when you debug the line of code here, assuming that you are using the debugger.. what is the value of newControl..? you can't access control1 you need to access and set properties on the newly declared variable `newControl` take time to reread how you're declaring the variables ..this is what the debugger is there for.. `control1.[some code here]` this line should be `newControl.` what ever property that's public you are trying to set..

Comment: Can you give more information about the error?  Also, why is the `MacName` property declared in the markup rather than in the code-behind?  Maybe it's not actually a class member when you do it that way?

Comment: great it work when i moved the properties to the code-behind and remove it from the script run at server. +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this isn't actually creating a class member:

```
<script runat="server">
    public string MacName = "UNKOWN";
</script>
```

Instead, put it on the code-behind as a class-level property:

```
class control1
{
    public string MacName { get; set; }

    // etc.
}
```

Then you should be able to set it on any instance of that type:

```
newControl.MacName = "some value";
```

Comment: yes im sorry the type used as variable accidently when i wrote the example i fixed that. but the problem is that i tried what you suggest newControl.MacName = "some value"; but newControl not recognize the MacName becuz it is not on the same page control